# Bootstrap affix offset bottom formula

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I am having a trouble getting formula for bootstrap affix layout. [Please check image for layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eWLEU.jpg).

All green sections height must be dynamic. Affix should move only in white region.

For top offset I use sections A height.
What formula should I use for bottom offset?

CSS side works fine (I guess).

Comment: Please embed your image into question.

Answer (score 0):

Try `calc()` formular, something like this.

```
height: calc(100% - HCpx);
```

Where `HC` is height of `C` in pixel. For Mozilla, Webkit or Opera browser, you will need to add redundant heights as:

```
.your_css {
    height: calc(100% - HCpx);
    /* mozilla */
    height:  -moz-calc(100% - HCpx);
    /* webkit */
    height: -webkit-calc(100% - HCpx);
    /* opera */
    height: -o-calc(100% - HCpx);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   $().affix({
    offset: {
    top: 0,
    bottom: function() {
      return(this.bottom = $('.footer').outerHeight(true))
    }
    });
```

try this for footer height.
i answered what im understood.
please expain clearly if not..thanks